# Simple replacement for the jQuery UI dialog box?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have started to use ASP MVC4 and I notice that they use jQuery UI dialog boxes. I like the idea of this but would like to have a more lightweight jQuery only based solution.

Is anyone aware of any simple dialog box plugin or other that I could use instead of the jQuery UI one?

Comment: What's wrong with the jQuery UI dialog?

Comment: It's not like jQuery UI dialogs are **heavyweight**.

Comment: Eh, you need a minimum of 100kb jQuery UI to use dialogs, that's not exactly lightweight either.

Answer (score 3):

There's no built-in dialogs in jQuery. You will have to build one yourself or use some existing dialog. That's why the jQuery UI project was created - to provide some commonly used UI elements. I don't know what exactly you mean by more lightweight but you could [build a custom jQuery UI package](http://jqueryui.com/download) that includes only the functionality you need and thus optimize the size of the javascript.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's referring to the jQuery UI dialog.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#dialog which has bunch of samples

Or you can have a look at this http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Even if there is **lightweight** alternative available I suggest not to use it.
The reason  I think is jQuery UI has better documentation and community support.